# Python loading data into MySQL: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

I know this has been discussed a couple of times but following the suggestions provided still did not solve my problem.
I tried to reproduce a youtube tutorial on updating a table:

Code:
Part1:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE testdab")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE users (name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), age INTEGER(10), user_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)")
```

Part2:

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
record1 = ("Peter", "peter@mail.com", 30)
cursor.execute(insert_query, record1)
```

The table is successfully created, but Part2 throws error message: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Anyone having an idea what's going wrong here?
Many thanks,
Thomas

Comment: The extras comma at the end of the line creates a tuple.

Comment: Following what suggestions? Which YouTube video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax problem at end of line after query
change
`insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",`
to
`insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"`
that comma makes `insert_query` a tuple and it cause the problem
because you have to give `cursor.execute()` a string at first argument and a tuple in second argument

Comment: Hi Aazerra, many thanks for your help and the explanation. It works!